# Finding a mask value with higher and lower position of the register

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c-preprocessor, bitmask, bit-masks

A 32 bit register i.e. status_reg has 1 field (field_1 <0:31>). To set and clear this register I am trying to get mask value of this register. So in general to get mask value the formula is:

```
mask = ((~(~0 << (hbit-lbit+1))) << lbit)
```

In this **hbit** is higher position bit i.e. 31. And **lbit** is lower position bit i.e.0.
I am expecting mask value should be 0xFFFFFFFF. But getting mask= 0. Can anyone suggest what is the wrong with mask?

I am using 32 bit system.

Comment: If you set `hbit` to `30` and `lbit` to `1` you get expected result of `0x7FFFFFFE`?

Comment: You're shifting left by 32, can't do that. Also from the description it doesn't look like any mask is necessary in the first place, `status_reg` has only one field and it's the *whole int*, what are you even masking for?

Comment: @harold is right, you don't need to mask to get a whole register value

Comment: @harold, I am just giving a simple example here. There are many other bit fields as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code doesn't give you the correct mask. If you like a mask for i.e. the bits 6..10 you can use `(1<<(hbit-lbit+2))-1)<<lbit`

Answer (score 0):

It shows undefined behaviour because you are left shifting outside of range, by 32 bits.